# Vuetify search/filtering multiple data using checkbox cannot show the result

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, filtering

I'm trying to create a simple task scheduler with filtering using a checkbox.

Here is my vue file.

In my templates,

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>TASK STATUS</legend>
    <span v-for="(item, index) in checkboxObj" :key="index">
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="task" :value=item.value>
        {{ item.name }}
    </span>
</fieldset>
<v-simple-table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>TASK</th>
            <th>STATUS</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(data, index) in filteredData" :key="index">
            <td>{{ data.task }}</td>
            <td>{{ data.status }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</v-simple-table>
```

In my data,

```
data(){
    return{
        recordList:[
            {task:'Cleaning Garage',status:'Due Today'},
            {task:'Checking Tools',status:'Overdue'},
            {task:'Repair Bikes',status:'Due Tomorrow'}
        ],
        task:[],
        checkboxObj: [
            {name:'OVERDUE',value:'Overdue'},
            {name:'DUE TODAY',value:'Due Today'},
            {name:'DUE TOMORROW',value:'Due Tomorrow'}
        ]
    }
}
```

And, I have this function,

```
computed:{
    filteredData() {
        if(this.task){
            for(let i = 0; i < this.task.length; i++){
                return this.recordList.filter((item) => {
                    return item.status.toUpperCase().includes(this.task[i].toString().toUpperCase())
                })
            }
        }else{
            return this.recordList
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have three(3) checkbox. Now, i want to show the status result every time i checked the checkbox. It's also have multiple filtering, so if i could check two to three check boxes, It will show the it's result.

The Final Output will look like.

*FROM THIS*
[image]

*TO THIS*
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the computed property like this:

```js
computed:
{
  chosenStatuses()
  {
    return this.task.map(item => item.toUpperCase());
  },
  filteredData() 
  {
    return this.chosenStatuses.length > 0 
      ? this.recordList.filter(item => this.chosenStatuses.includes(item.status.toUpperCase()))
      : this.recordList;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @IVO GELOV, Now I understand it and very minimalist codes with the help of ternary operator.